# Spatial sound on entity with aframe.js and howler.js

Tags: aframe, howler.js

I've looked all over for examples online but to no avail.

Trying to play a howler sound through an entity in my A-frame scene so it can be heard relative to the camera. Tried several approaches and none seem to work.

Howler is defined like so:

```
var voice = new Howl({
  src: ['./mp3/voice.mp3'],
  autoplay: false,
  preload: true,
  loop: true,
  volume: 1
});
```

...and I have a component set up on an entity. Tried reaching into A-frame's sound capabilities and bodged some pos() stuff with howler, struck a dead end. How is this done? Any and all feedback appreciated.

Comment: Just by curiosity, what are you trying to achieve with howler that you can't with the built-in sound component? https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/sound.html It's pretty straight-forward to use and you get spatial sound without anything more than that.

Comment: Hi Stephane, I managed to figure out a way to do it. The game I'm developing required lots of updating of mp3's for each character, and every time I've used aframe's in-built sound, it's either been a little choppy, unable to loop properly, unreliable or setting volume reliably across browsers was taking too much time. In the end I randomized the mp3's on interval and changed URL / path to new audio sources, which seems to have worked well.